# How to enable 5.1 sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I edited the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to make it `6`:

```
stephen@stephen-Aspire-TC-605:~/$ cat /etc/pulse/daemon.conf | grep channel
; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
default-sample-channels = 6
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
```

after restarting I still get only stereo in the sound settings. installed the pavucontrol and still nothing. the 5.1 is connected with three jacks on the back, not hdmi. Something is missing

```
tephen@stephen-Aspire-TC-605:~$ speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -l1 -twav

speaker-test 1.2.2

Playback device is plug:surround51
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
WAV file(s)
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
tephen@stephen-Aspire-TC-605:~$ aplay -L |grep 5.*1
surround51
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
```

... with many rows about hdmi, dmix and dsnoop

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have true 5.1 speakers and they are properly connected:

From `etc/pulse/`, copy `daemon.conf` and `default.pa` to your user's home folder. (If you've altered these configs previously, copy from your backup of the original files):

```bsh
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

Add the following line to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Add (or uncomment) the following lines in `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
remixing-produce-lfe = yes
remixing-consume-lfe = yes
lfe-crossover-freq = 80
```

Without the `lfe-crossover-freq` defined, it defaults to `0`, which is not very helpful.

You can replace `80` with the desired crossover frequency (in Hz).  Frequencies below this value will be sent to the LFE channel.  Frequencies between 80Hz - 120Hz are generally recommended for the LFE crossover.

To enable the new settings, restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k`.  Some applications could require a restart.

Comment: still does not work. the surround profiles show as unavailable in pulseaudio control https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPS_-bkP2_FqyciXxBm8_7GCxit8d2Sl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I found it. start alsamixer and then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to select sound card. select HDA Intel PCH and then you see this:

[image: alsamixer]

then click right arrow until you get to the channels and click up arrow to set it to 6 channel

[image: alsamixer]

Now you will get the full surround mode and it works great. I did that after making the changes suggested in the previous answer, so do that too. But choosing the card and changing the channels in alsa is crucial.